# How to type these Unicode characters or make my own character?

Tags: character-encoding, unicode

How can I type the following characters without copying and pasting them from the web? Perhaps define them as a character myself?

Also, they are not displayed properly when pasted in a code cell but when if it is printed as a string, it is displayed correctly. Is there way to fix this issue so it can be used as a normal character in Mathematica?

Unicode: [U+1D132](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d132/index.htm)

Unicode: [U+1D133](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d133/index.htm)

On a similar note, is it possible to generate my own charactres using LaTex? That is, convert the output of this LaTex into a character?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\sori{\stackengine{1pt}{\ensuremath{>}}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{%
  \scalebox{-1.3}[1]{\textsl{=}}}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
\sori
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your $\LaTeX$ questions should be asked at the [$\LaTeX$ site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is not a LaTex question. I have generated a symbol using LaTex and want to use that on Mathematica. But I don't know how or if it is even possible.

Comment: That character goes beyond plane-0, which is the one currently supported by Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica can input UTF-16(hex). For U+1D132 the hex is 0xD834 (or 0xDD32). So you just type in the notebook \:d132  . It does not mean that you will see the symbol, because not all fonts have these symbols present. But with menu cell/show expression command (shift+ctr+E) you can check that the cell do contain the character. Once you will find the font which has this symbol, then you can define your own style sheet with the command below (it was taken from [Is there a global setting for Mathematica's base fonts?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113478/is-there-a-global-setting-for-mathematicas-base-fonts/113480#113480))

```
setFont[fontFamily_, fontSize_] := 
 With[{styleNB = 
    Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
      Cell[StyleData["StandardForm"], 
       FontFamily -> ToString[fontFamily], 
       FontSize -> ToExpression[fontSize]]}], 
   styleSheetName = 
    FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
      "StyleSheets", "My_Style.nb"}]}, 
  If[FileExistsQ[styleSheetName], 
   SetOptions[$FrontEnd, DefaultStyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]];
  Export[styleSheetName, styleNB];
  SetOptions[$FrontEnd, DefaultStyleDefinitions -> styleSheetName]]
```

And then set it with, say,

```
setFont["Microsoft Sans Serif" , 14]
```

Unfortunately, I had tried a number of fonts on my linux system, but the character always was displayed as an empty square or question mark (i.e. the tested font do not have the symbol defined)

Comment: `\:d132` is [a Hangul character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d132/index.htm), not a musical symbol.