# how to get unicode for tally mark in mathematica

Tags: unicode

People are saying u1D378 is the unicode for

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Tally_marks-Five-bar_Gate.svg

How do i create such a tally mark character in mathematica front end. If there is another way please also suggest that.

Comment: According to http://www.unicode.org/alloc/Pipeline.html, the Tally Mark Five character was finally published in Unicode 11, on June 5 2018. Since no version of Mathematica is newer than that, I don't believe the built-in font has support for these characters (my OSX system font also doesn't have support for these characters). Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557276/how-to-represent-tally-five-bar-gate-in-unicode#34797279 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159178/how-to-type-these-unicode-characters-or-make-my-own-character?rq=1

Comment: I believe *Mathematica* implements only UTF-16 Unicode characters, so the characters that look like u plus 5 hex digits can't be used in *M*.  See `FromCharacterCode[]` and try `FromCharacterCode[16^^1D378]`.

Comment: I think version 12 will support emoji, so perhaps support for higher-register UTF characters will come via that 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it seems impossible to get the true unicode character to display in Mathematica (see comments), you can create a graphics expression that behaves like a character in terms of display (code at the end of the answer):

[image]

You can copy this object into a string, and it will adapt to font color and size (copy & paste the result from above to where the `<>` is):

```
Style["This is like a character: <>",Red,FontSize->30]
```

[image]

This is achieved by wrapping the graphics expression in `Dynamic` (to get the dynamic color/size) and `Deploy` (to prevent accidental editing). The color is set to `CurrentValue@"Color"`, the size is set using `CurrentValue@FontSize`. Similarly, other properties of the object could be adapted to the surrounding text. I got the graphics expression itself by printing the SVG file to a PDF and importing that into Mathematica.

#### Code to generate expression

```
Dynamic@Deploy@Graphics[
  {
  CurrentValue["Color"],
  FilledCurve[
    {{{1,4,3},{1,3,3},{0,1,0},{1,3,3},{1,3,3},{0,1,0}}},
    {{{191/2,2771/5},{479/5,2732/5},{961/10,2693/5},{963/10,2654/5},
    {967/10,2596/5},{969/10,2538/5},{971/10,496},{461/5,2463/5},
    {92,2521/5},{459/5,5157/10},{457/5,5273/10},{456/5,5351/10},
    {909/10,543},{453/5,2754/5},{191/2,2771/5}}}
  ],
  FilledCurve[
    {{{1,4,3},{1,3,3},{0,1,0},{1,3,3},{1,3,3},{0,1,0}}},
    {{{847/10,2771/5},{85,2732/5},{426/5,2693/5},{171/2,2654/5},
    {859/10,2596/5},{861/10,2538/5},{863/10,496},{407/5,2463/5},
    {406/5,2521/5},{81,5157/10},{403/5,5273/10},{803/10,5351/10},{80,543},
    {399/5,2754/5},{847/10,2771/5}}}
  ],
  FilledCurve[
    {{{1,4,3},{1,3,3},{0,1,0},{1,3,3},{1,3,3},{0,1,0}}},
    {{{739/10,2771/5},{741/10,2732/5},{372/5,2693/5},{747/10,2654/5},
    {751/10,2596/5},{753/10,2538/5},{151/2,496},{353/5,2463/5},
    {352/5,2521/5},{701/10,5157/10},{349/5,5273/10},{139/2,5351/10},
    {346/5,543},{69,2754/5},{739/10,2771/5}}}
  ],
  FilledCurve[
    {{{1,4,3},{1,3,3},{0,1,0},{1,3,3},{1,3,3},{0,1,0}}},
    {{{631/10,2771/5},{633/10,2732/5},{318/5,2693/5},{639/10,2654/5},
    {321/5,2596/5},{129/2,2538/5},{647/10,496},{597/10,2463/5},
    {119/2,2521/5},{593/10,5157/10},{589/10,5273/10},{587/10,5351/10},
    {292/5,543},{581/10,2754/5},{631/10,2771/5}}}
  ],
  FilledCurve[
    {{{1,4,3},{1,3,3},{1,3,3},{1,3,3},{0,1,0},{1,3,3},
    {1,3,3},{1,3,3},{1,3,3},{0,1,0}}},
    {{{246/5,2729/5},{272/5,543},{60,2697/5},{326/5,2681/5},{153/2,5293/10},
    {439/5,522},{99,5147/10},{516/5,5121/10},{1073/10,5093/10},
    {557/5,2532/5},{561/5,2529/5},{113,5053/10},{1137/10,2524/5},
    {548/5,2503/5},{1089/10,2506/5},{1081/10,5017/10},{537/5,2511/5},
    {1033/10,5051/10},{991/10,5079/10},{95,2553/5},{837/10,2589/5},
    {145/2,5251/10},{611/10,532},{557/10,5353/10},{50,5383/10},{449/10,2712/5},{246/5,2729/5}}}
  ]
  },
  ImageSize->{Automatic,CurrentValue[FontSize]},
  BaselinePosition->Scaled[1/10]
]
```

Comment: Although i used `FontVariations->{"StrikeThrough"->True}]` to achieve a slightly poor effect but this is brilliant. Can this be used to convert any image data into a character to be used in the frontend?

Comment: @user13892 In principle, you can insert anything into strings, yes. Dynamic styling is also pretty straightforward - just wrap the expression in dynamic and use `CurrentValue[…]` to get the correct values (the are many others besides `"Color"` and `FontSize`, just play around with it - see also [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/items-known-by-currentvalue))